# why we use polymorphism and abstract classes in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I first learned polymorphism in c++, in c++ we had types for every variable. So we used polymorphism to get a single pointer which can point to different type objects, and we could use them very nice.

But I don't get polymorphism and abstract classes in python. Here every variable can be everything. It could be an iterator, a list, a singe variable or a function. Every thing. So what makes a programmer to use an abstract class or use polymorphism here?

In c++ we used inheritance in many ways. But in python, it is just used to use another classes method or attribute. Am I right? what's the matter?

Comment: The same reason we use polymorphism and abstract classes in other languages: to do different things depending on the object's type, and to share common implementation details across multiple concrete classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't understand what polymorphism is (OO polymorphic dispatch I mean). Polymorphism is the ability to have objects of different types understanding the same message, so you can use those objects the same way without worrying about their concrete type.

C++ actually uses the same concept (class) to denote two slightly different semantics: the abstract type (interface) which is the set of messages an object of this type understand) and the concrete type (implementation) which defines how this type reacts to those messages.

Java clearly distinguishes between abstract type (`interface`) and concrete type (`class`).

Python, being dynamically typed, relies mostly on "duck typing" (if it walks like a duck and quack like duck, then it's a duck - or at least it's "kind-of-a-duck" enough). You'll often find terms like "file-like" or "dict-like" in Python docs, meaning "anything that has the same interface as a file (or dict)", and quite a few "interfaces" are (or at least have long been) more or less implicit.

The issue with those implicit interfaces is that they are seldom fully documented, and one sometimes have to get to a function source code to find out *exactly* what the object passed needs to support. That's one of the reasons why the `abc` module was introduced in python 2 and improved in python 3: as a way to better document those implicit interfaces by creating an abstract base type that clearly defines the interface.

Another reason for abstract base classes (whether using the abc module or not) is to provide a common base implementation for a set of  concrete subclasses. This is specially useful for frameworks, ie Django's `models.Model` (ORM) or `forms.Form` (user input collection and validation) classes - in both cases, just defining the database or form fields is enough to have something working.

Inheritance in C++ suffers from the same issue as classes: it serves both as defining the interface and implementation. This adds to the confusion... Java had the good idea (IMHO) to have separate abstract type from implementation, but failed to go all the way and restrict typing to interfaces - you can use either classes or interfaces for type declaration, so it still doesn't make the distinction clear.

In Python, since we don't have static typing, inheritance is mostly about implementation reuse indeed. The abc module allows you to register totally unrelated classes (no inheritance relationship) as also being subtypes of a defined abstract base case, but the point here is mostly to document that your class implements the same interface (and that it's not an accident...).